# how to write syntax in sql like that ? because i have an error in this. (with php)

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY `posts`.`postid` DESC WHERE postid < ".$_POST['last_video_id']." LIMIT 8 ;
```

Comment: Well your order by is in the wrong place and you have SQL injection problem... what is the error exactly?

Comment: You should place the WHERE before the ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the conditions in your query in the correct order

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE postid < ?
ORDER BY postid DESC 
LIMIT 8
```

And you should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) that savely fill the parameters in your query.